# Cant import FBX in Unity, getting exeption Framerate was set to 0.00, it's been reset to 1.0

Tags: unity-game-engine, import, blender, fbx

[There are inverted faces, and actually I cant solve this problem I d be greatfull for you hints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvW6v.png)

I tride invert faces in blender, use briges, but I didnt work at all

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently having this issue. No matter what I tried, I could not get it to work.

I read somewhere else that someone's blender was the issue.

What I did to fix this was simply copy everything in blender into a new blender file, did the export with the exact same settings and it seemed to work. I imagine somewhere in that previous blender file, I had changed some setting somewhere and was breaking it in the export.

I hope this helps!